# How do I connect my Galaxy Y GT-S5360 via USB to my Mac?

Tags: usb, settings, samsung-galaxy-y, usb-mass-storage

I cannot connect my Galaxy Y phone to my MacBook for mass storage using a USB cable. I have installed Android File Transfer software but it does not detect my phone when I connect it. I believe I have to change the USB / Mass Storage settings on my phone but cannot find them in the Settings. I have disabled USB Debugging in Settings > Applications > Development but there is no USB setting in Wireless and Networks. Where do I find the USB Mass Storage settings in my Galaxy Y phone?
Tim, London

Comment: Tim, what Android version have you running? What options does your phone give you? With Android 4.x, many devices discarded UMS, and switched to MTP. Please see the [tag-wiki for UMS](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-mass-storage/info) for some more details (btw: you can find such basic info for many tags here, just hover your mouse over the tag, and select the "info" link in the popup).

Answer (score 1):

Any time if you connect your android mobile device to a laptop/desktop, you just switch over to "Notifications" and select the option which is for Connecting your mobile phone to devices. Click on the 'Connect to Storage' option.